# Change DB that Access query points to

Tags: sql, ms-access, sqlconnection, ms-access-97

I'm trying to make a query in Access 97 point to a different database.  I cannot find out how to change the db.
I've tried adding another odbc connection but it doesn't give me the option to choose it when running the query.

I've tried to create another query but it still has the old db tables and i cannot choose the new db tables.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

thanks,
Nighmares

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try viewing the SQL source of your query.  Is the old database name there?  Can you just replace it and save your change?  Another option would be to point your existing ODBC connection to the new database.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Turns out I had to go to the SQL source and change the schema name to the new one.  all the tables were the same only the schema name changed.

Answer (score 0):

when you add another ODBC database Access will give you the option to add tables from it. You'll need to add whichever tables you need or you won't be able to access them via design view.

You can always use the [Connection object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681519%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to dynamically connect to any DB.